# dimensions getting reduced after reading image in R

Tags: r, jpeg

I am reading a jpeg image in R having 128*128 pixels

```
library(jpeg)
img <- readJPEG("C:/Users/rohit.gupta/Desktop/training_data/ferrari/1.jpg")
```

but when i am looking at dimensions , its showing:

```
> dim(img)
[1] 102 102   3
```

Why is it so?
Thanks

Comment: what happens if you try `img <- readJPEG("C:/Users/rohit.gupta/Desktop/training_data/ferrari/1.jpg"), native=TRUE)`?

Comment: > dim(img)
[1] 102 102